# Qt compilation error unicode/uloc.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile Qt x64 libraries with the following configure command

```
D:\Qt\Qt5.0.0src>configure -prefix %CD%\qtbase -release -opensource -icu -platform win32-msvc2010 -opengl desktop
```

following this guide 
http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/#comment-7546

then launching the jom.exe file (extracted into D:\Qt\Qt5.0.0src) with

```
jom.exe -j7 /P
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Generating Code...
qlocale_win.cpp
tools\qstring.cpp(3841) : warning C4309: 'argument' : truncation of constant value
tools\qstring.cpp(3842) : warning C4309: 'argument' : truncation of constant value
qstringbuilder.cpp
Generating Code...
qlocale_icu.cpp
tools\qlocale_icu.cpp(48) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/uloc.h': No such file or directory
qharfbuzz.cpp
Generating Code...
jom: D:\Qt\Qt5.0.0src\qtbase\src\corelib\Makefile.Release [.obj\release_shared\qelapsedtimer_win.obj] Error 2
jom: D:\Qt\Qt5.0.0src\qtbase\src\corelib\Makefile [release] Error 2
jom: D:\Qt\Qt5.0.0src\qtbase\src\Makefile [sub-corelib-make_first] Error 2
jom: D:\Qt\Qt5.0.0src\qtbase\Makefile [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
jom: D:\Qt\Qt5.0.0src\Makefile [module-qtbase-make_first] Error 2
```

The main point is:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unicode/uloc.h': No such file or directory
```

this file is located into "D:\Qt\icu\include\unicode" and I added both D:\Qt\icu and D:\Qt\icu\bin64 to the Path environment variable.

Why can't the makefile find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved -> I hadn't installed Windows SDK 7.1 before